# Getting Device Info From A Iphone/Ipad/Ipod using C#

Tags: c#, ios, mobile, information-retrieval

So, Im trying to get the name, IOS, and capacity of a idevice when it is plugged in. I then want to transfer that information to a label on the form. I cant find anything anywhere that tells me what I should do. Someone Please Help!! :D

Comment: You can create a PC application and from the application send using wi-fi an UDP broadcast with a message like "Who is". Then you can develop an App for your iDevice that uses an UDP listener and when receive the "Who Is" message replies with the device information or custom strings. I hope this can help you to find an idea